# Is there a way to fetch Json values within Json?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I've got a Scenario Entity in my Spring boot app

```
private Long id;

private String scenarioName;

private HashMap<Integer, Object> scenarioAttributes;
```

Let's say we create a Scenario entity with following Json:

```
{
"scenarioName":"scenario1",
"scenarioAttributes":{
    "1" : {
        "goToURL":"https://google.com/"
    },
    "2" : {
        "assertCurrentUrl":"https://google.com/"
    }
}
}
```

In my ExecutorService, I've got following code:

```
public List<Object> getStepsFromScenarioAttributesValues(Long scenarioId){
        List<Object> response = new ArrayList<>();

        Scenario scenario = scenarioService.getScenario(scenarioId);
        HashMap<Integer, Object> steps = scenario.getScenarioAttributes();
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Object> set : steps.entrySet()){
            response.add(set.getValue());
            System.out.println(response);

            // prints out 
            //[{goToURL=https://google.com/}, {assertCurrentUrl=https://google.com/}]
 

        }
        return response;


}


public void executeSteps(List<Object> response){
        
        for (Object obj : response){
            JsonObject jsonObj = (JsonObject) obj;

            if (jsonObj.has("goToUrl")) {
                //goes to url
                driverService.goToUrl(String.valueOf(jsonObj.get("goToUrl")));
                return;
            } else if (jsonObj.has("assertCurrentUrl")) {
                //asserts cur url with value
                driverService.assertCurrentUrl(String.valueOf(jsonObj.get("assertCurrentUrl")));
                return;
            }
        }
    }

public String executeScenario(Long scenarioId){
        executeSteps(getStepsFromScenarioAttributesValues(scenarioId));
        return "Scenario" + scenarioId + " has been executed successfully";
    }
```

I've got a GetMapping for single scenario as follows:

```
@GetMapping("/scenarios/{id}/execute")
    public List<Object> executeScenario(@PathVariable Long id){
        return executorService.getStepsFromScenarioAttributesValues(id);
    }
```

Which, upon sending one sample scenario and entering a site, provides us with, you guessed it, a List containing an Object, which is a Json.

Unfortunately, if I want to call executeSteps() function which has a list of Objects, I cannot do it since an Object is not a JsonObject.

I thought simple `JsonObject jsonObj = (JsonObject) obj;` would do a trick, but I'm greeted with
`class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class com.google.gson.JsonObject (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.google.gson.JsonObject is in unnamed module of loader 'app')`

How can I approach fetching values from scenarioAttributes Jsons to further interpret them?
Are there unnecessary lines of code that I could get rid of?

Feel free to point out my wrongdoings, just starting my journey with Spring

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Scenario {
    private String scenarioName;
    private HashMap<Integer, Object> scenarioAttributes;
}
```

Use object mapper to print class object to JSON:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Scenario scenario = objectMapper.readValue(response, Scenario.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say `Object, which is a Json` what do you mean by "Json"? Json is not a class. I assume that your Object is an instance of class `String` that contains text in Json format. Your exception though points out that it could be a `Map`. I would still assume that it is a `String` that holds Json. In your code you attempt to work with class `JSONObject` which is part of [json-simple](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple) library. While it is a nice training library I would suggest that you don't use it. BTW great site about JSON with the list of most libraries for most languages is: https://www.json.org/json-en.html. Best options are (IMHO) are [Jackson-Json (also known as Faster XML)](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) (by Google) (Here is their [user guide site](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide)). To parse your Json text to a class instance you can use `ObjectMapper` class which is part of Jackson-Json library. For example

```
public <T> T readValue(String content,
              TypeReference valueTypeRef)
            throws IOException,
                   JsonParseException,
                   JsonMappingException
```

See [Javadoc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class)). But I also may suggest a very simplified `JsonUtils` class which is a thin wrapper over Jackson-Json library. This class is part of Open-source library called MgntUtils written and maintained by me. Your code may be as simple as follows:

```
Scenario scenario;    
try {   
        scenario = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString(response, Scenario.class);
     } catch(IOException ioe) {
       ....
     }
```

Here is [JsonUtils](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html) javadoc. MgntUtils library can be obtained as Maven artifact [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or on [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including source code and Javadoc)