# get a key value pair from a String json (simple object)

Tags: java, json, string

Im trying to get a key:value pair from a simple jsonString to add it after into a memory tab. If facing an issue cause my input is a string. and it looks like my  loop isnot able to read the key value pair.

I read many topics about it, and im still in trouble with it. As you can see below

```
{"nom":"BRUN","prenom":"Albert","date_naiss":"10-10-1960","adr_email":"abrun@gmail.com","titre":"Mr","sexe":"F"}
```

and my method, find only on object... the result is the same in my loop

```
public static ArrayHandler jsonSimpleObjectToTab(String data) throws ParseException {
        if( data instanceof String) {
        final var jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        final var object = jsonParser.parse(data);
        final var array = new JSONArray();
        array.put(object);
        final var handler = new ArrayHandler("BW_funct_Struct");
        for( KeyValuePair element : array) {
            handler.addCell(element);
            Log.warn(handler);
        }
        return handler;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("jsonSimpleObjectToTab: do not support complex object" + data + "to Tab");
        }
    }
```

i also tryed before to type my array as a List, Object etc, without the keyValuePair object, i would appreciate some help.

Thanks again dear StackOverFlowers ;)

Answer (score 0):

Simply split the whole line at the commas and then split the resulting parts at the colon. This should give you the individual parts for your names and values.

Try:

supposing

```
String input = "\"nom\":\"BRUN\",\"prenom\":\"Albert\"";
```

then

```
String[] nameValuePairs = input.split(",");

for(String pair : nameValuePairs)
{
    String[] nameValue = pair.split(":");

    String name = nameValue[0]; // use it as you need it ...
    String value = nameValue[1]; // use it as you need it ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```java
const json = '{"nom":"BRUN","prenom":"Albert","date_naiss":"10-10-1960","adr_email":"abrun@gmail.com","titre":"Mr","sexe":"F"}';
 
map = new Map();
const obj = JSON.parse(json,(key,value) => {
     map.set(key,value)
});
```

and you'll have every pair stored in `map`

Answer (score 0):

You can use TypeReference to convert to Map<String,String> so that you have key value pair.

```
String json = "{\"nom\":\"BRUN\",\"prenom\":\"Albert\",\"date_naiss\":\"10-10-1960\",\"adr_email\":\"abrun@gmail.com\",\"titre\":\"Mr\",\"sexe\":\"F\"}";
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    TypeReference<Map<String,String>> typeReference = new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {
    };
    Map<String,String> map = objectMapper.readValue(json, typeReference);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a very similar question. The gist of it is that you need to parse your Json String into some Object. In your case you can parse it to Map. Here is [the link to the question with my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72536189/is-there-a-way-to-fetch-json-values-within-json/72543736#72543736). But here is a short version: you can use any Json library but the recommended ones would be [Jackson Json (also known as faster XML)](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) or [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)(by Google) Here is their [user guide site](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide). To parse your Json text to a class instance you can use `ObjectMapper` class which is part of Jackson-Json library. For example

```
public <T> T readValue(String content,
              TypeReference valueTypeRef)
            throws IOException,
                   JsonParseException,
                   JsonMappingException
```

See [Javadoc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class)). But also I may suggest a very simple `JsonUtils` class which is a thin wrapper over `ObjectMapper` class. Your code could be as simple as this:

```
Map<String, Object> map;    
try {   
        map = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString(input , Map.class);
} catch(IOException ioe) {
       ....
}
```

Here is a Javadoc for [JsonUtils](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html) class. This class is a part of MgntUtils open source library written and maintained by me. You can get it as [Maven artifacts](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or from the [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases)